# PowerShell e VS Code não reconhece "Set-Location"

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, powershell, prompt

Meu `PowerShell` não reconhece o `Set-Location`, isso já ocorria a um tempo toda vez que eu executo um código no VS Code porque meus trabalhos e projetos estão na nuvem e em outro HD mas nunca dei importância porque rodava normal.

Mas agora não consigo abrir nenhum terminal na própria pasta ou fazer a navegação alternando os HDs

Erro:

```
Set-Location : O termo 'Set-Location' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa
operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente
novamente.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ Set-Location -Path 'G:\OneDrive\Gui\GuiTestes\Python\Projetos ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-Location:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

(Esse eh o mesmo erro que aparece no terminal do VS Code)

.

Eu verifiquei no `PowerShell ISE` os comando "instalados" e o `Set-Location` realmente não aparece (e também um outro comando `set-variable`, descobri indo no `ISE`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar `Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` antes do [`Set-Location`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7)?

Comment: Ok.. Isso funcionou, mas eu vou precisar fazer isso manualmente quando eu precisar usar o Set-Location ou qualquer outro comando. Não alguma forma de arrumar isso?

Comment: Você está usando o Windows 10? Se não estiver verifique a versão do PowerShell, tive um problema parecido tentando rodar um script em um Windows 7 e tive que instalar a versão mais nova do PowerShell

Comment: Podia ter usado `pushd` e `popd` que fazem a mesma função.

Comment: Não conhecia esses comandos.. Mas pelo que eu percebi não era só o `Set-Location` que estava com esse erro, outros comandos estão com esse problema. Mas obr pela dica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom.. eu consegui resolver.

Realmente se vc acrescentar antes de qualquer comando (nativo do PowerSheel) a linha `Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` e depois o comando do próprio PowerShell (que não esta reconhecendo) funciona.

Porém isso só resolve manualmente e eh um saco ficar fazendo isso..

[image]
(abri o PowerShell na pasta, deu erro e depois fiz os comandos)

.

> Instalando o novo `PowerShell`

O que eu fiz foi instalar o novo `PowerShell 7.0` (versão do mais atualizada do momento)
A versão que eu baixei foi a `PowerShell-7.0.3-win-x64.msi` (89 mb) nesse [repositório](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases) (que do próprio novo powershell).

A versão `.msi` instala direto e o próprio Windows já configura. Já a versão `.zip` eh como se vc tivesse copiado o programa para o seu computador, ou seja, não está instalado de fato com o sistema mas eh acessivel.
Sugiro baixar a `.msi`.

O `PowerSheel 7.0` não subtitui o `PowerShell 5`, a própria Microsoft fala isso, eles de certa forma trabalham juntos. Mas ele aparece direto com o botão direito do mouse e tb com o `shift + x`, podendo até escolher se você quer como adm ou não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

.

> Ajustando o terminal do VS Code:

Como o VS Code tem o terminal integrado dele, que eh nada mais que o PowerShell (você percebe pelo `PS` escrito no começo da linha), nas configurações vc consegue alterar o terminal, podendo escolher qual vc quer (pode ser qualquer um da sua preferência, até algum que vc baixou).

Nesse [link](https://www.it-swarm-pt.tech/pt/visual-studio-code/como-redefinir-configuracoes-no-visual-studio-code/823306763/) mostra como alterar o terminal. Caso esteja com algum outro problema com o terminal, esse [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch) te dá algumas alternativas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha sugestão pra você eh instalar esse novo `PowerShell 7.0`, vale muito pena e eh mais 'limpo'.

Comment: Era apenas caso de colocar aquela linha do `Import-Module` dentro de um perfil global assim todos os shells iniciados já importariam o módulo ou então então um perfil específico para que apenas o perfil escolhido iniciasse com a carga do módulo. Sugestão de leitura [PowerShell || About Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Achei mais fácil instalar o novo, que ele inclusive já aparece quando clico com o botão direito.. Mas obr pela dica

Answer (score -3):

Para quem está passando mesma situação (rs)

digite no terminal

```
notepad $profile
```

Vai abrir o bloco de notas onde é possível fixar algumas configurações. Cole a linha

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

Agora ele deve funcionar tranquilo :)